# Is there any formula to automate multiplication with the equation within the string in Excel?

Tags: excel, bigdata, formula, inventory

Given the example:

| ITEM | Quantity in Pieces |
| --- | --- |
| BRAND A AA 6X5X40ML | 30 |
| BRAND B BB 24X20ML | 24 |
| BRAND C CC 2X12X20ML | 24 |
| BRAND D DD 20X2X2KG | 40 |

Is there any way that I can fetch/automate the equation in inside the string? Note that some items doesn't have any multiplier and just straight up quantity.

I have 5,000+ items and I did manually multiply them one by one. Its quite tedious to do it again manually.

Comment: If the last entry is always a unit type and not a quantity, you can split the string using `TEXTSPLIT` on `space` and `X`, then multiply the **antepenultimate** (if it is a number) and **penultimate** values to get the quantity.

Answer (score 3):

From your current sample you may try-,

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(A2,,{" ","X"}),PRODUCT(--FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(--(x)))))
```

To get results as dynamic spill array use `MAP()` or `BYROW()`.

```
=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(lm,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(lm,,{" ","X"}),PRODUCT(--FILTER(x,ISNUMBER(--(x)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: sir, I have shorten the formula.. 
=PRODUCT(IFERROR(--TEXTSPLIT(A2,,{" ","X"}),1))
also gives the same result. @Harun24hr